# Way to check if first iteration in map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add a class to an element within ReactJS using the map function, but ONLY for the first one in the loop, is this possible / an easy way?

```html
return (
  <div key={itemData.itemCode} className="item active">
    Want to add 'active' class when the first but for the others dont add it
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Can you explain where your `map` function is being used? It's not present in the code snippet.

Comment: the second argument for the map callback function is the index, so you can check if the index is zero: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 22, accepted):

If you use `.map` or `.forEach` then you can do it like this

```
var List = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var lists = this.props.data.map(function (itemData, index) {
         /// if index === 0 ( it is first element in array ) then add class active 
         var cls = (index === 0) ? 'item active' : 'item'; 

         return <div key={itemData.itemCode} className={ cls }>
           { itemData.itemValue }
         </div>;
      })
      return <div>{ lists }</div>;
    }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/25009/)

also there is good package called [`classnames`](https://github.com/JedWatson/classnames) if you need conditionally change classes, like as in your case

```
var List = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
      var lists = this.props.data.map(function (itemData, index) {
        return <div 
            key={itemData.itemCode} 
            className={ classnames('item', { active: index === 0 }) }>
          { itemData.itemValue }
        </div>
      })
      return <div>{ lists }</div>;
    }
});
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/_alexander_/69z2wepo/25011/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a slight simplification of the accepted answer for the general case:

```
items.map(item, index) => {
  if (index === 0) {
    // First item...
  }
  // ...
}
```